# do ros suport mpi? Can High-performance computing integrated into ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros for fuete has related thing about mpi , why next versions of ros no longer suport mpi?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179880/do-ros-suport-mpi?-can-high-performance-computing-integrated-into-ros?/) by [lligen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19238/lligen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS doesn't natively support using MPI for message-passing between nodes. It uses sockets for inter-process communication, and shared pointers for intra-process communication. These are generally fast enough for most users.

Judging by the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/mpi), the MPI stack was probably experimental, and it looks like it wasn't fully integrated with ROS. There's no in-depth documentation, no tutorials, and it isn't released.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lligen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19238/lligen/) on 2014-06-30**:
Thank you for your reply. Would you mean that there is no need to integrate mpi into ros?  Then, how can we accelerate our programs when it contains  large amounts of calculation? Distributed computing, cloud computing, can it work with ros?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-01**:
ROS nodes are simply C++ or Python programs; you can do anything you would in a normal C++ program, including using libraries outside of ROS.